# Multi-level metis menu items keep opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, asp.net-mvc-5, sidebar

I'm new to "MetisMenu" JavaScript library.

I need to know how to keep menu items state if opened or closed on page refresh or redirect to another page.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is somewhat old but I figured I would write up how this could be handled for anyone else faced with a similar issue.

This is a architecture related question for the most part - but the best advice I can give is to persist the data in: cache, session, state, session storage, or local storage (last two are browser storage of course). This really depends on how your app is built.

Please see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp - this is how you could store the state.

Many considerations could be taken into how you would like to go about this and maintaining it.  A state storage may also work for you - such as redux: https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Essentially you would store and read state and set the nodes you would like open accordingly, store the state, on subsequent page loads you would load your state and apply the state to the menu.

A quick way to do this is to apply an id to each menu item and store this in your state or storage in a list.  This list then can be iterated and have a class / selector applied to it on page load/state load - however your app works.

The metis menu method to state the class you would like for active menus is its activeClass property:

```
  $("#menu").metisMenu({
    activeClass: 'active'
  });
```

Review: https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu for details on setting your activeClass and other API information.

You would then use a jquery selector to apply that class to the menus you would like to have open via add class:

```
$( "#menuId1, #menuId2, #menuId3" ).addClass( "active" );
```

- jQuery Add Class: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
- jQuery Multiple Selector: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

The items included in your selector could be the id's of the menus you would like open or whatever method you choose to organize that aspect of tracking what should have its active status set.